# I can't import Scipy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scipy

I'm having a problem using some codes in python/VS code

Some time ago, I tried to use a code, and a noticed a problem, this same problem, appears now when I tried to use a code to solve some integration problems.

I tried to use scipy, but I'm having problems importing, I already install the scipy, but I continue having the same problem.

That's the code, I'm trying at least import.

`import scipy`

In the terminal, appear `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'`, and in the problems "Import "scipy" could not be resolved"

I'm using Visual Studio Code, 1.70, windows 7, and python 3.8.8

Comment: _I already install the scipy_ You must have installed it for a different version of Python than VS Code is using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`

  [image]
- Select the **correct** interpreter (The one who installed the `scipy` package).
- ***Also ensure the use of **Python** extension***

  [image]

Comment: I tried all other options of the Python interpreter, but none of them worked. When I selected the 3.6.0 interpreter, there was no problem, but nothing happened when I ran the code.

Comment: How are you executing the code? Are you using `Run Python FIle`?

Comment: It took a long time, but it worked. You were right. I used 'Run Python file' and now it works. Thanks!